# Nintendo Switch Controller delayed response on Android TV 9

Tags: bluetooth, android-tv, game-controllers

I'm owning a *Xiaomi Mi TV 4A* that runs Android TV 9. I would like to play games on it with the [SNES -aka Super Famicom- Nintendo Switch Bluetooth controller](https://mynintendostore.nintendo.ch/de/super-nintendo-entertainment-system-controller-for-nintendo-switch.html).

Connecting the controller works but there is a big delay after pressing a button and there are random other issues like multiple steps instead of one after pressing the D-Pad in a direction.

Is this an issue with the controller or are there settings I'm missing?

I updated the OS, tried reconnecting the Gamepad and rebooting the TV without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sadly this is an issue with Nintendo Switch Controllers**

While Nintendo Switch Controllers use Bluetooth HID, they aren't completely conforming to the specification which means that you'll need a modified driver (and that is hard on Android).

Bluetooth HID (Human Interface Device) is the spec that allows for bluetooth keyboards, mice, and gamepads to communicate with supporting devices.

So I found this project trying to [document the interface to the Nintendo Switch](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/blob/master/USB-HID-Notes.md). As can be seen at the end of [Issue #7 HID protocol for Bluetooth/USB](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/issues/7) there has been some success on Linux, but [Issue #92 for Android has remained unanswered](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/issues/92).

Changing the bluetooth driver is a Custom ROM level change. A compatible Android bluetooth driver would have to be made and support your bluetooth chipset and your platform hardware. As you are running TV hardware, I have doubts that any Custom ROMs exist, and then writing a driver supporting the Bluetooth chipset would be a further obstacle.

Based on:

[Nintendo Switch Reverse Engineering HID Notes](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/blob/master/USB-HID-Notes.md)

[Issue #7 - HID Protocol for Bluetooth / USB](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/issues/7)

[Issue #92 - How to communicate with joycon in Android platform?](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/issues/92)